# In this basic react application, why does the custom component `TextInput` allow me to type stuff in even though the regular `input` field doesn't?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a basic react form that I am testing out currently. It's still incomplete, but I have discovered unexpected behaviour.

The regular input field doesn't allow me to type in anything, as I am not updating the state yet. However, my custom `TextInput` component does allow me to type stuff in... Surprising, as I said before, I am not using `setValues` to update the state yet.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  });

  
  return (
    <div>
      <form>

    {/* [EXPECTED]  this doesn't allow anything to be typed in at the front-end... which is expected...
        ... as I am not using `setValues` to update the state yet */}
        <input
            type="text"
            id="first-name"
            name="firstName"
            value={values.firstName}
        />

    {/* [NOT EXPECTED] this does allow stuff to be typed in at the front-end... which is strange...
        ... as I am not using `setValues` to update the state yet */}
        <TextInput
          id="last-name"
          name="lastName"
          value={values.lastName}
        />


        <button type="submit">
          Register
        </button>

      </form>
    </div>
  );
};


const TextInput = props => {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      id={props.id}
      name={props.name}
    />

    /* <span id={props.id + '-error'}>{props.title}</span> */
  );
};


export default App;
```

Can anybody help me to explain why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first input is [*controlled*](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-input-null-value) - it has a `value` prop which is used to determine what the value of the element should be when rendered:

```
<input
    type="text"
    id="first-name"
    name="firstName"
    value={values.firstName}
/>
```

No matter what you type into it, since it's "controlled", the value that exists in it will always be what's currently in state as `values.firstName`.

In contrast, your second input is *uncontrolled*. It has no `value` prop:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id={props.id}
  name={props.name}
/>
```

So, since you're not giving React any directives on what its value should be while being rendered, you can type whatever you want into it, and it won't be in conflict with React state.

Comment: Aaaah! The penny just dropped thank you. I mean, I thought `TextInput` was controlled as I added `value={values.firstName}` at the top while using it. However, I've now realised that it has to be added within the `TextInput` declaration not just when it's being used. Perfect, thanks!